# Whats the difference between the .length use in for loops in ajax and the .length use for number output?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I notice that the for loop AJAX version doesn't output numbers like the other one why is that? 
[The number version link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)

and the AJAX version.

**INPUT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<button id="bg" type="button" onclick="x()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function x() {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
var employees = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
for(var i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
    employee = employees[i];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br>' + employee.name;
}
}
};
xhr.open("GET", "burgerking.json", true);
xhr.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT**

Steve
Dan
Ken

Comment: The length attribute always returns a number. In your `for` loop, it returns the length of the `employees` variable that you created. More generally, a length attributes in for loops is used to loop until the length of the iterable object is reached.

Comment: Its *length of a name* vs *number of names*.

Comment: So If I understand you correctly the .length one that is use in loops is responsible in producing all the letters of each property? For example Steve, Dan and Ken? And the other non loop version is used to count the letters? For example Steve = 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It boils down to difference between **string.length** and **Array.length** in JavaScript.

The link you shared is an example of [`string.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property of a string in JavaScript, read on :
The length property represents the length of a string.
**Syntax** : `str.length`
*Return the number of characters in a string*

```
var x = 'Mozilla';
var empty = '';

console.log('Mozilla is ' + x.length + ' code units long');
/* "Mozilla is 7 characters long" */

console.log('The empty string has a length of ' + empty.length);
/* "The empty string has a length of 0" */
```

Whereas in code sample above you are trying to access `employees` array one element at a time, `employees.length` provides total no employees OR total number of elements in the array, read on :

The **length** property of an object which is an instance of type Array sets or returns the number of elements in that array.

```
var items = ['shoes', 'shirts', 'socks', 'sweaters'];
items.length; 

// returns 4
```

In code snippet you shared above :

```
for(var i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
    employee = employees[i];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br>' + employee.name;
}
```

You are iterating over an array , when you write :

```
for(var i=0;i<employees.length;i++)
```

This means you will loop until `i` is less than `employees.length`
**`employees.length`** returns a **number** like examples shared above.

Once you're inside for loop execution block use `i` to access specific element of the `employees` array.You refer to an array element by referring to the index number. like this :

**employee** is a variable which holds **i** th element of **employees** array

```
employee = employees[i];
```

You access ***name*** property of ***employee*** variable which returns a text output

```
employee.name // returns John
```

Also it is important to note that in JavaScript **[String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)** is **sequence of characters**. In other words an array of characters.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your response but after playing with the array and the string version it still gives me a number count as an output and I know that I know it gives you a count back as an output but in that ajax example why didn't it gave me a numerical response back but instead it gave names of people can you explain that? That's what i'm confused about.

Comment: Edited my answer in response to your comment above !